# Stream insertion combined with postfix operators

Tags: c++, operators, postfix-operator

Say I was reading data in which the indexing starts at 1. I want my indexing to be 0 based.

Why is it not acceptable to use postfix increment/decrement operators after a stream insertion operator?

```
int a;
std::cin >> a--;
```

Comment: It doesn't compile for one thing.

Comment: won't even compile...

Comment: Because you got your operator precedence wrong?

Comment: By the way, the relevant error message is `note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument operator>>(int& __n);`. [Dietmar Kühl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26809155/3920237) is correct. This has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of a post-increment operator is a temporary object, even if the increment is strictly applied only at the end of the expression. To read a value, an lvalue is needed but temporary objects aren't lvalues: they are bound to go away. Note, that you'd also read the value into the temporary, retaining an unspecified value in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`operator>>` has an overload that takes a `int&`. The result of `a--` is an rvalue, and you can't bind a non-const reference to an rvalue.